# Where can turtlebotsim camera/depth data be found?

Tags: ros, gazebo, kinect, camera, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using gazebo to simulate a turtlebot,
rostopic list shows

/camera/depth/points

/camera/image_raw

/camera/image_raw/compressed

/camera/image_raw/theora

among others.  I want to get a representation of the kinect's depth data using

rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/depth/points

or something to that extent.
However, when I run that command, I just get an empty window that gives the same results as replacing /camera/depth/points with a string that isn't listed in rostopic.
When I connect my laptop to a kinect sensor, the directory that the point data is stored is something like /camera/kinect/depth, but the rosrun command brings up a small window that accurately shows depth of whatever is in front of the kinect sensor.
Is it possible to obtain similar data from the turtlebotsim in gazebo?

Thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28082/where-can-turtlebotsim-camera/depth-data-be-found?/) by [jfetsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1816/jfetsch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to display the /camera/depth/points use Rviz. Subscribe to the PointCloud2 topic /camera/depth/points and it will display it. However, for some people (like me), the data displayed is a flat PointCloud. I hope for you it works. Have you solved your problem ?

---

Originally posted by [Yannis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2569/yannis/) with karma: 88 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1